# is there any waySimplest way to add a AsciiFolding filter to Turkish language analyzer?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

i need this structure  "nest->analysis->analyzer->filter->asciifolding".i realized that [from this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html).

Because

I'm preparing an in-site search engine with elasticsearch and I'm new to elasticsearch. Sites which will use this engine are Turkish / English.

In Turkey, we have Turkish letters like 'ğ', 'ü', 'ş', 'ı', 'ö', 'ç'. But when we search generally we use the letters 'g', 'u', 's', 'i', 'o', 'c'. This is not a rule but we generally do it, think like a habit, something we used to.

My goal is this:

ProductName or Category.CategoryName may contain Turkish letters ("Eşarp") or some may be mistyped and written with English letters ("Esarp")
Querystring may contain Turkish letters ("eşarp") or not ("esarp")
Querystring may have multiple words
Every indexed string field should be searched against querystring (full-text search)
My code is : (Not working)

```
  public static Uri EsNode;
    public static ConnectionSettings EsConfig;
    public static ElasticClient EsClient;

    EsNode = new Uri("http://localhost:9200/");
        EsConfig = new ConnectionSettings(EsNode);
        EsClient = new ElasticClient(EsConfig);

        EsClient.CreateIndex("employeeindex2", ci => ci
.Settings(s => s
    .NumberOfShards(1)
    .NumberOfReplicas(0)
    .Analysis(analysis => analysis
        .TokenFilters(tokenfilters => tokenfilters
            .AsciiFolding("folding-preserve", ft => ft
                .PreserveOriginal()
            )
        )
        .Analyzers(analyzers => analyzers
            .Custom("folding-analyzer", c => c
                .Tokenizer("standard")
                .Filters("standard", "folding-preserve")
            )
        )
    )
)
.Mappings(m => m
    .Map<Employee>(mm => mm
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(p => p
            .String(s => s
                .Name(n => n.Name)
                .Fields(f => f
                    .String(ss => ss
                        .Name("folding")
                        .Analyzer("folding-analyzer")
                    )
                )
                .NotAnalyzed()
            )
        )
    )
)
);

        Employee emp = new Employee() { Name = "yılmaz", SurName = "eşarp" };
        EsClient.Index<Employee>(emp, idx => idx.Index("employeeindex2"));
        Employee emp2 = new Employee() { Name = "ayşe", SurName = "eşarp" };
        EsClient.Index<Employee>(emp2, idx => idx.Index("employeeindex2"));
        Employee emp3 = new Employee() { Name = "ömer", SurName = "eşarp" };
        EsClient.Index<Employee>(emp3, idx => idx.Index("employeeindex2"));
        Employee emp4 = new Employee() { Name = "gazı", SurName = "emir" };
        EsClient.Index<Employee>(emp4, idx => idx.Index("employeeindex2"));
    }
}

public class Employee
{


    public string Name { set; get; }

    public string SurName { set; get; }


}
```

My Search Query :

```
namespace Atom.Customer.Service
{
    public class SearchCustomerService
        : CustomerModuleServiceBase
    {
        [MainMethod("1.0")]
        public SearchCustomerResponseEntity MainMethodV1(SearchCustomerRequestEntity searchCustomerPhrase)
        {
            var searchCustomerResponse = new SearchCustomerResponseEntity();
            var elasticClient = new ElasticSearchClient();
            var client = elasticClient.GetClient("employeeindex2");
            var searchResults = client.Search(s => s
                .AllTypes()
                .From(0)
                .Size(10)
                .Query(q => q.Bool(p => p.Must((m => m
                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                        .DefaultField("_all")
                        .Query(searchCustomerPhrase.Query))))))
            );
            searchCustomerResponse.TotalCount = searchResults.HitsMetaData.Total;
            searchCustomerResponse.Customers = searchResults.Hits.Select(h => h.Source).ToList();
            return searchCustomerResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your search query look like? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: @RussCam I updated my question above .